# WPF Different behaviour when drawing point versus line

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes

I am attempting to draw a line from the center of an image on a canvas to the mouse's position when the scroll wheel is moved.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
// e is MouseWheelEventArgs
var position = e.GetPosition(canvas);
var x = Canvas.GetLeft(image) + image.ActualWidth / 2;
var y = Canvas.GetTop(image) + image.ActualHeight / 2;

Ellipse point = new Ellipse
{
    Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0)
};

Line line = new Line
{
    X1 = position.X,
    Y1 = position.Y,
    X2 = x,
    Y2 = y
};

canvas.Children.Add(point);
canvas.Children.Add(line);
```

The point is drawn correctly at the pointer's location, and the line is drawn from the center of the image, but the point the line is drawn to is incorrect. Why is this?

Here is an image to show the location of the point and the line
[image: Image showing incorrect line]

Comment: Do not use Margings to position elements in a Canvas. Use SetLeft and SetTop instead. In order to draw a centered circle, either set the Ellipse's Margin to the negative of its radius, or use a Path with an EllipseGeometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to implement this with Geometries.

With a XAML like this

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel">
    <Image x:Name="image" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Source="..."/>
    <Path x:Name="line" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    <Path x:Name="point" Fill="Red"/>
</Canvas>
```

the event handler could look like this:

```
private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);

    var center = new Point(
        Canvas.GetLeft(image) + image.ActualWidth / 2,
        Canvas.GetTop(image) + image.ActualHeight / 2);

    line.Data = new LineGeometry(center, position);
    point.Data = new EllipseGeometry(position, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it out. Unfortunately it put both points of the line in incorrect positions.

Comment: Incorrect in which sense? Not sure what else you have added to this sample. The code shown here positions one line endpoint at the image center and the other at the mouse position.

Comment: My mistake, I had some instructions in the wrong order, the point of the line where the mouse is, is drawn correctly, but the center is not in the center.

Comment: Maybe your image is stretched. Don't know. Is it a direct child of the Canvas? Do you set its Width or Height? Does that match its aspect ratio?

Comment: It gets transformed with a matrix. I ended up using the center of the grid instead